# Cascading deletion of Images in JPA models

Tags: java, jpa

I have JPA entities with a relation between articles and images:

```
Article {
   @Id
   Long id;

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")) 
   Set<Image> images;

   ...
}


Image {
    @Id
    Long id;

    ...
}
```

To delete remove the image from the set in Article, I can juste use `this.images.remove(image)` and JPA will take care of the removal from the Join Table, which is fine.

What I would like to achieve is that the Image entity would be removed as well, once there are no articles pointing at it. The problem also is, that the images are stored in files, so there must be some kind of handler, which would take care of them as well.

What is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is sometimes known as orphan deletion.  JPA can handle it for one-to-many relationships (the deleteOrphans attribute on the OneToMany annotation, if you're using JPA 2.0 or greater) but not for ManyToMany.  You will either have to handle it yourself or see if your JPA provider has the capability.